# PHPUnit in Eclipse cannot create test case from existing class

Tags: php, eclipse, phpunit

I have installed PTI plugin in my Eclipse Luna in order to use PHPUnit. Whenever I try to create a test case from a existing php class (right click over the php file -> New -> New PHPUnit Test case) the dialog doesn't work (the "Finish" button seems to do nothing):

[image]

After checking the Eclipse log I found this error:

> org.eclipse.ui Error Thu Jul 23 19:09:39 CEST 2015 Unhandled event
>   loop exception
>
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.eclipse.php.internal.debug.core.preferences.PHPDebuggersRegistry.getDebuggerConfiguration(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/eclipse/php/internal/debug/core/debugger/AbstractDebuggerConfiguration;
>     at
>   org.phpsrc.eclipse.pti.core.launching.PHPToolLauncher.createConfiguration(PHPToolLauncher.java:376)
>     at
>   org.phpsrc.eclipse.pti.core.launching.PHPToolLauncher.findLaunchConfiguration(PHPToolLauncher.java:265)
>     at
>   org.phpsrc.eclipse.pti.core.launching.PHPToolLauncher.launch(PHPToolLauncher.java:136)
>     at
>   org.phpsrc.eclipse.pti.core.launching.PHPToolLauncher.launch(PHPToolLauncher.java:117)
>     at
>   org.phpsrc.eclipse.pti.tools.phpunit.core.PHPUnit.createSkeleton(PHPUnit.java:178)
>     at
>   org.phpsrc.eclipse.pti.tools.phpunit.core.PHPUnit.createTestSkeleton(PHPUnit.java:131)
>     at
>   org.phpsrc.eclipse.pti.tools.phpunit.core.PHPUnitUtil.syncPHPClassToTestCase(PHPUnitUtil.java:174)
>     at
>   org.phpsrc.eclipse.pti.tools.phpunit.ui.wizards.CreatePHPUnitTestCaseWizard.performFinish(CreatePHPUnitTestCaseWizard.java:33)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:853)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:438)
>     at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:619)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4454)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1388)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3799)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3409)
>     at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:832)    at
>   org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:808)     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.NewWizardShortcutAction.run(NewWizardShortcutAction.java:136)
>     at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:519)    at
>   org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4454)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1388)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3799)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3409)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)  at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: a recent bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=473050

Comment: So, I have to rebuild whole eclipse in order to apply the link solution?